# Animate moving a usercontrol to new grid position

Tags: silverlight, animation

I have a simple Silverlight (v5) `Grid` with a fixed number of rows and columns. On this grid, I'm positioning several UserControls (called `myControl` in this example) at specific "grid coordinates" e.g. row 2, column 1.

Occasionally, I need to move a `myControl` to a new grid position; I currently do this by

```
 Grid.SetColumn(myControl, newColumn);
 Grid.SetRow(myControl, newRow);
```

.. and this all works fine, `myControl` is moved to the new coordinates.

Just purely for eye candy, I'd like to animate `myControl` when it moves, so that it "slides" from the old grid position to the new one rather than just appearing. Is there an easy/quick way to do this?

Comment: You could try attaching `FluidMoveBehavior` to your `Grid` and see if that's the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: @ChrisW. *Exactly* what I'm looking for - please post this as the answer so I can upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For handling layout changes within an element to display a smooth transition `FluidMoveBehavior` is generally the option you would be looking for. While it won't animate things like size or visibility, it is however specifically for animating the offset of a child element moved around a parent container.

Glad you found your answer. Cheers